# Rails partial template with collection not rendering correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, partials, renderpartial

I have been troubleshooting this error for hours and I have no idea what I’m doing wrong. I simply can’t get the items collection to properly display for an individual user. Each item belongs to a single user and each user has many items. Right now, my partial is not rendering on the users show view.

If I change `<%= render partial: "/users/item", collection: @user.items %>`
 to `<%= render partial: "/users/item", collection: @items %>` then the partial template is rendered, but all items are displayed regardless of which user they belong to. After checking the database, each item entry is being properly stored with a foreign key user_id, so that isn’t the issue.

**How do I get the correct items to display for each user?** I have used partials several times before and I’ve cross-referenced old and new code. I can’t see the difference and I’m losing my mind. I’ve searched the general internets, Stack Overflow, and reviewed the [Rails Guides for Layouts and Rendering](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html). I've posted the relevant code below and happy to post anything else. Please help!

**views/users/_item.html.erb**

```
<div>
  <h4>ITEM: <%= item.title %></h4>
  <p class="item"><%= item.cost %></p>
</div>
```

**views/users/show.html.erb**

```
<h1>Users#show</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/users/show.html.erb</p>

<div><%= @user.first_name %></div>

<h3>My List</h3>
<%= render partial: "/users/item", collection: @user.items %>

<span>ADD ITEM&nbsp;<%= link_to image_tag("Plus-50.png"), new_user_item_path(@user), class: "items-nved" %> </span>
```

**controllers/users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @users = User.all
    render :index
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    # @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    @items = Item.all
    @item = Item.new
    @item.user_id = @user.id
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      redirect_to new_session_path, method: :get
    else
      render "new"
   end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
  end

  def destroy
  end

  private
  def set_user
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :birthday, :city, :state, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

**controllers/items_controller.rb**

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController

  include ItemsHelper

  before_filter :require_login, only: [:new, :create, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @current_user = current_user
    @items = Item.all
  end

  def show
    @user = current_user
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = current_user
    @item = Item.new
  end

  def create
    @user = current_user
    @item = Item.new(item_params)
    @item.user_id = params[:user_id] # set user_id param from database to current_user id
    @item.save

    redirect_to user_item_path(@user, @item)
  end

  def edit
    @user = current_user
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
   @user = current_user
   @item = Item.find(params[:id])
   @item.update(item_params)
   redirect_to user_path(@user)
  end

  def destroy
    @user = User.find params[:user_id]
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    @item.destroy
    redirect_to user_path(@user)
  end
end

private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :birthday, :city, :state, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end

  def require_login
    unless logged_in?
      flash[:error] = "You must be logged in to access this section"
      redirect_to new_login_url # halts request cycle
    end
  end
```

Comment: u can just pass `@user` like this `collection: @user` and loop it in render file `@user.items`. Also try like this `<%= render partial: "/users/item", locals: {user_items: @user.items} %>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the byebug gem, either by running `gem install byebug` on your command line or by putting byebug in your Gemfile (then run `bundle install`).

Put `byebug` just after the @user declaration in your UsersController, like this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @users = User.all
    render :index
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    byebug
```

Then start your local server and go the user show view in your browser. The page won't render, because when it hits `byebug` the server pauses.

When this happens, go back to your Terminal and look at your server log. It will be waiting for your commands. Type `@user` and press Enter. What does it return?

Also try `@user.inspect`. Does it return a User object?

Then do `@user.items`. What does that return? If `@user.items` returns the expected collection of items, then there is something wrong with how you are passing that to the view, or what you're doing with it in the view.

If `@user.items` doesn't return a collection of items, then that's why it isn't showing in your view! In this case, it's probably something to do with your ActiveRecord associations and/or your migrations.

Another possibility is that the current Items in your database may have been created before you had the associations setup, so they won't have a user_id. You can check this in your rails console. Make sure you have Items in your database that have the same user_id as your current_user.

Another good thing to do in your rails console would be to assign a User, that you think has some Items, to a variable eg `user = User.first`, and then do `user.items`. Does that work?

I also recommend writing some RSpec tests, at least at Model level to test that the proper associations exist. The [shoulda gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda) is great for this.

Comment here with your findings.

Comment: Thank you!! `@user.inspect` returns the correct user object. However, `@user.items` does not return the expected collection of items, so my ActiveRecord associations and/or migrations are the issue! Oddly, my rails console shows that each item is being assigned a user_id foreign key and my user model has  `has_many :items, :foreign_key => 'user_id', :primary_key => 'user_id'` and my item model has `belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => 'user_id', :primary_key => 'user_id'`, so I’m still not clear as to why  `@user.items` does not return an items collection. I'm thinking it's likely my migrations.

Comment: Try changing those declarations in your Models to just: `has_many :items` in your User model, and `belongs_to :user` in your Item model. However, before or after doing this you will also have to reverse some previous migrations. You could do this like this: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#reverting-previous-migrations (more elegant but slightly more complex). Personally, just because I'm lazy, I would probably just create new migration files to drop the User table and Item table completely and then run migrations to build them with the proper associations.

Comment: Google `drop_table` for rails migrations for how to drop tables. You might hit database problems, but remember if you get in a proper muddle, you can always just do `rake db:drop db:create db:migrate` which will completely destroy and rebuild your database, based on your current migration files (you will have to add data again after this). Again, I'd recommend writing some RSpec tests with the shoulda gem, because I _think_ (but I'm not sure) it doesn't just test the association declarations in your models, but also that your db schema is setup properly.

Comment: This would save a lot of time in the long run (the beauty of TDD!)

Comment: I can’t thank you enough for the incredibly detailed help! After modifying my models as you’ve described, I ran `rake db:rollback STEP=6` (I had a lot of migrations), edited my migration files according to [RailsGuides - Changing Migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/migrations.html#changing-migrations), and then ran `rake db:migrate`. I then created some new users and added items to each. Now my items and user are showing up correctly when the partial renders! THANK YOU!

Comment: Hey that's really great! Very glad I could help. Good effort getting all of that fixed - reversing migrations and sorting out the database can be very confusing when you're not used to it, so big pat on the back to you - glad you got it sorted.

Comment: Oh and knowing how to debug is probably the most important skill (but this is a skill that you're always improving on and never truly master), but you have to know what tools to use. In short, for Rails, byebug (or pry), rails console, and `puts` are your friends. Also, in general, when writing new code, take the smallest possible, simplest possible, babysteps and test each step as you go (either manually or using TDD).

Answer (score 0):

Try to render it like this:

```
<%= render partial: "/users/item", locals: {user_items: @user.items} %>
```

and loop it in _partial file:

```
<% user_items.each do |item| %>
...
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I tried to the render the partial as described above, and while the template renders static elements, I am still unable to display the item data, much less the item data tied to a specific user.

Answer (score 0):

You're expecting the template rendering to be smarter than it is - it's rendering all the items because that's what's in `@items` - it doesn't know you only want items for a given user. Nothing wrong with the original code

```
render partial: "/users/item", collection: @user.item
```

Comment: Exactly, the original code should work but it should also render items for a given user. I've used the same format before and this is the first time I've had a problem. From my limited previous experience, `<%= render partial: "/users/item", collection: @user.items %>` should display items associated with a particular user since calling the `.items` method on `@user` should result in an array of the user's associated item objects. This tutorial does a better job explaining [See Displaying Comments for an Article](http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/blogger.html#i2:-adding-comments).